# Prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I was reading the proof for the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra in Ian Stewart's book *Galois Theory*. The author defines $p(w+h)=p_0+p_1h+p_2h^2+\dots+p_nh^n$ for $h\in\Bbb{C}$, then he lets $h=\varepsilon e^{i\theta}$ for small $\varepsilon>0$. Let $m$ be the smallest integer $\ge1$ from which $p_m\neq0$. Then he claims that "$p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})=p_0+p_m\varepsilon^me^{mi\theta}+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$, where $O(\varepsilon^{n})$ indicates terms of order $n$ or more in $\varepsilon$, and therefore
$|p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})|^2=|p_0+p_m\varepsilon^me^{mi\theta}|^2+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$."

My question: why do we have $|p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})|^2=|p_0+p_m\varepsilon^me^{mi\theta}|^2+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$?

I know little to nothing about complex numbers and complex analysis; but using a theorem without understanding the proof is against my religion. Please help if you can - many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then he claims that "$p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})=p_0+\color{red}{p_m\varepsilon^{mi\theta}}+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$

I assume that was meant to be $\,p_m\color{red}{\varepsilon^m}\varepsilon^{mi\theta}\,$ instead. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
\left|p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})\right|^2 &= p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})\,\overline{p(w+\varepsilon e^{i\theta})} \tag{1}
\\ &= \left(p_0+p_m\varepsilon^m\varepsilon^{mi\theta}+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})\right)\,\left(\overline{p_0+p_m\varepsilon^m\varepsilon^{mi\theta}}+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})\right) \tag{2}
\\ &= \left|p_0+p_m\varepsilon^me^{mi\theta}\right|^2+O(\varepsilon^{m+1})\cdot\left(O\left(\varepsilon^0\right)+O\left(\varepsilon^0\right)+O\left(\varepsilon^{m+1}\right)\right) \tag{3}
\\ &= \left|p_0+p_m\varepsilon^me^{mi\theta}\right|^2+O(\varepsilon^{m+1}) \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Step by step:

$\;\;{(1)}\;$ using that $\,|z|^2 = z \,\overline{z}\,$ for all complex $\,z\,$;

$\;\;{(2)}\;$ using that $\,\overline{z_1+z_2}=\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2}\,$ and $\,\overline {\,O(\varepsilon^k)\,} = O(\varepsilon^k)\,$ for real $\,\varepsilon\,$;

$\;\;{(3)}\;$ using that $\,a + b \cdot \varepsilon^k+\dots = a \color{red}{\cdot \varepsilon^0} + b \cdot \varepsilon^k+\dots=O\left(\varepsilon^0\right)\,$;

$\;\;{(4)}\;$ using that $\,O(n_1)\,\pm\,O(n_2) = O\left(\min (n_1,n_2)\right)\,$ and $\,O(n_1)\,O(n_2) = O(n_1+n_2)\,$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! And you are correct-I have fixed the typo. Still, it seems that I lack quite a bit of foundational knowledge required to understand the machinery at work here. I am not quite sure why $O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$ remains unchanged when taking the conjugate: doesn't $O(\varepsilon^{m+1})$ also contain terms such as $p_n\varepsilon^n e^{ni\theta}$ for some $n>m$?

Comment: @Josh12913 I added a few notes about each step at the end of the answer. The notation $\,O(\varepsilon^k)\,$ describes a function in terms of the powers of $\,\varepsilon\,$. For that purpose $\,p_n\varepsilon^ne^{ni\theta}\,$ is just an $\,n^{th}\,$ power $\,\alpha \,\varepsilon^n\,$ with a coefficient $\,\alpha \in \mathbb C\,$. Since $\,\varepsilon\,$ is real, it follows that $\,\overline {\,\alpha \,\varepsilon^n\,}= \overline\alpha\, \varepsilon^n = O(\varepsilon^n)\,$.

Comment: I couldn't thank you enough; but it seems like I must build a deeper foundation in the complex numbers before I could fully comprehend this proof.

Comment: @Josh12913 Glad it helped. And you are right, there is only so much that can be covered here, and Q&As cannot replace a good textbook for establishing the foundations.